# Difference between form submit and 302 redirection in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

want to understand what is the difference between a form submit by creating a jsp page in Spring and doing a 302 API redirect

for example I can create a get or post API redirect by redirecting to other url

```
httpServletResponse.setHeader("Location", fun.generateEnrolURL());
httpServletResponse.setStatus(302);
```

similarly I can create a get api with return type ModelAndView and in the jsp create submit

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("body").append('<form method="post" action="' + '${endPoint}' + '" id="superMan"></form>');
        $("#superMan").append('<input type="hidden" name="SITE" value="' + '${abc.site}' + '"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="LANGUAGE" value="' + '${abc.language}' + '"/>
        $("#superMan").submit();
    });
</script>
```

since both of these can redirect to another page which approach should be used at what scenario

Comment: `which approach should be used at what scenario` - form submit sends a request (mostly post) to the server, while 302 redirection is a response (to a request), they are not interchangeable.